# How do I join a conference call in Skype for Linux?

Tags: linux, skype

On Linux, the latest Skype client doesn't seem to allow joining conference calls, only creating new ones. Clicking on the call button (I think) calls each member separately, I've been told by the other participants. How can I join an existing conference call with that client? I tried running the Windows client under Wine, but login doesn't work.

Comment: Also, I can join if another person initiates the call.

Comment: Bogdacutu. Your comment is really more information related to your question, so it would be better to put it into the question itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two types of *joining* methods.  1. joining via a web-link. 2. joining from within Skype itself.

Although method 1 seems quite possible to do in a normal manner, I haven't actually got it working properly (yet?), but that may just be my system, and it may work for you. Howerver, I can explain how to use method 2.

If you aren't already in the conference/chat, you first need to know the conference ID. This is available by issueing the [Group Chat Command](https://support.skype.com/en-gb/faq/FA10042/What-are-chat-commands-and-roles) `/get uri`  into the message area.  This creates a URL link that other people (or you) can use to join the group chat.

Clicking on the `skype:?chat&blob=...` URL ia any Skypw chat window or entering it into your web browser's address-bar will start Skype (if it isn't already running) and join the conference.

Now comes the problem I have encountered (which isn't much of a problem, really). Although this link works fine in Windows, it doesn't work properly for me. It starts Skype, but doesn't join the chat.. (one day, I may finally work it out ?), but it doesn't matter that much, as you don't need it after the first time you join the chat/converence.

To subsequently join the conference whenever you want to, you simply need to `bookmark` the chat/conference. To join the conference, click on your Skype bookmark. That's it.

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE 2016:
My company used and uses Skype regularly, here is what we found lately:

Linux clients cannot join group calls started from Windows clients.
Windows clients can join group calls started from Linux clients.

On the Skype forums it looks like Microsoft have abbandoned the Linux development.
http://community.skype.com/t5/Linux/Why-is-Skype-on-Linux-still-so-grossly-out-of-date/td-p/4304329

Comment: By any chance can you add a source where people can go for further information?